# Substitute character

Tags: java, unicode, char, символы, ascii

Всем доброго времени суток! В очередной раз просматривая JLS наткнулся на интересный момент, на который доселе не обращал внимания. Речь идёт о параграфе 3.5 в котором отмечается, что в качестве символов входного потока данных могут использоваться не только входные элементы, но и управляющий ASCII-символ, известный как “Ctrl-Z” или SUB (в мнемоническом представлении), если этот символ идёт последним в потоке. Насколько мне известно, то этот абстрактный символ также именуется ”символом замены“ и используется в тех случаях, когда значение какого-либо символа было утрачено при передаче или же сам символ является некорректным. Собственно говоря, мой вопрос заключается примерно в следующем: каков практический смысл этого символа и какова его семантика в контексте языка программирования Java? Есть ли какое-либо преимущество от его использования или же наоборот недостаток? Является ли это рудиментом из 90-х годов прошлого века или же актуально и на сегодняшний день? Как обычно, благодарю всех за Ваши ответы и помощь в освоении языка программирования Java!

**P.S.** Для понимания вопроса обсуждения считаю возможным привести продукцию из JLS:

```
Input:
    {InputElement} [Sub]

InputElement:
    WhiteSpace
    Comment
    Token

Token:
    Identifier
    Keyword
    Literal
    Separator
    Operator

Sub:
    the ASCII SUB character, also known as "control-Z"
```

Comment: И всё-таки, кто-нибудь сможет дать более-менее ясный ответ по данному вопросу? Спасибо!

Comment: Ctrl+Z во входном потоке - это признак его окончания.

Comment: `{InputElement} [Sub]` означает 0 или более `InputElement` за которыми может следовать один `Sub` (а может и нет) в конце потока, где он благополучно игнорируется для совместимости с "некоторыми операционными системами". см. пояснения к [jdk-4209933](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-4209933)